# Python TypeError: temperature() missing 1 required positional argument: 'float'

Tags: python, spyder

I just started to learn Python. I tried to create a new function, but the terminal keeps returning the same kind of error.

> TypeError: temperature() missing 1 required positional argument: 'float'

Below is my code:

```py
def temperature(celsius, float) -> float:
        fahrenheit = (celsius*(9/5)+32)
        return fahrenheit
celsius = float(input("Input the temperature in Celsius that you want to have in Fahrenheit: "))
temperature(celsius)
print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is: ", temperature, "°F")
```

Can you help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: It is because you are giving one parameter instead of 2, to your function definition. There is no need. You could just do this ```def temperature(celsius) ```

Comment: I think you want `def temperature(celsius: float) -> float:`

Comment: Oh, ok I used the def temperature(celsius: float) -> float: but now I'm getting: temperature in Fahrenheit is:  <function temperature at 0x000001D65A207AF8> °F as the result

Comment: Do something like this:  ``` temp = temperature(celsius)```  and then  ```print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is: ", temp, "°F")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this be what you are looking for. Remove the float from the parameter list in the temperature function? With celsius and float as parameters your temperature function was expecting you to pass it two parameter. You only needed to pass it one celsius.

Also, you need to store the return of the tempurature method before printing it. Notice how I modified the last to lines with the `temp` variable. You store the output of the temperature function call in temp. Then you print temp on the last line.

```
def temperature(celsius) -> float:
    fahrenheit = (celsius*(9/5)+32)
    return fahrenheit
celsius = float(input("Input the temperature in Celsius that you want to have in Fahrenheit: "))
temp = temperature(celsius)
print("The temperature in Fahrenheit is: ", temp, "°F")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Comment: check out my latest edit. I forgot to add the temp variable first

Comment: If you can mark the answer as answered if it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the function definition as `def temperature(celsius, float)` and not `def temperature(celsius)`? It will work exactly the same with the latter definition, and would not return any error